# Setup git in wsl2 windows

Tags: git, github

How can I setup the git in wsl? I cannot get it setup

Tried installing and setting but getting error
`fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com`

Comment: Are you using a firewall either on Windows or in WSL? Are you behind a proxy? Are your network settings in linux correct? BTW, probably a better place would be: https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download WSL and Ubuntu from Windows
2. Type `sudo apt update`
3. Type

`sudo touch /etc/resolv.conf`

`sudo chmod 777 /etc/resolv.conf`

`sudo printf 'nameserver 8.8.8.8\nnameserver 4.4.4.4' > /etc/resolv.conf`

4. Install git by `sudo apt install git`
5. `git config --global --add safe.directory '*'`
6. git clone your repo repository
7. Add your credentials by using a personal token as password is outdated
8. `git config --global credential.helper store` (optional to store the credentials)